# Does VisualVM support REST API?

Tags: rest, performance-testing, visualvm

Currently I am working on the subject *Performance Testing* and make a research for tools that perform such testings. For me it is important that the tool has *Pre and Post Processing* for **REST** service calls.

I did not find in the internet, whether it is possible with **VisualVM**. Does anyone have more information about the tool?

**EDIT:** It would be interesting to find out the following, too:

- does it have a low overhead?
- are custom performance profiles possible?
- how reliable is the performance tracking?